# How to set breakpoint programmatically in IE extension?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, javascript-debugger

Did some homework on this. I saw one can set breakpoints using `debugger` in JavaScript source code. However, I am wondering if I could set a breakpoint in IE extension programmatically. Say, once IE discovers JavaScript source code on some callback function, I could set breakpoints via its PC or line#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no JavaScript mechanism that allows you to set breakpoints programmatically *other than the `debugger` statement*. Your best option would be to express 'decision' and result in an `if (something) { debugger; }` style statement.

That said, the IE dev tools, like other browsers, allow you to set breakpoints *conditionally*[image: conditional break point dialog]. All you need to do is to to right-click when you add the breakpoint and then select that it's conditional. In the condition you can enter anything that'll return a `true` result.

Comment: Are there any callback like `onBreakpoint()` and `onFunctionCall()` etc via IE extension? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, none of the dev tools expose that as far as I'm aware